# Laravel 5.3 : Users having multiple roles in teams

Tags: relational-database, laravel-5.3

I'm having a project where

1.Users

- a)Sam
- b)Ram

having multiple roles

2.Roles - Roles of users with hierarchy

- a) owner-9
- b) manager-7
- c) coach-5
- d) player-3

3.Teams types are having hierarchy

- a) Football-10
- b) Basketball-9
- c) Vollyball-8

4.Team Type Roles: - Permissions will be depending on team type roles

- a) Football-owner laravel-permissions
- b) Football-coach laravel-permissios
- c) Vollyball-player
- d) Basketball-manager

5.Football_teams: all football teams

- a) football-team-1
- b) football-team-2

6.Basketball_teams : all basketball teams

- a) basketball-team-1
- b) basketball-team-2

Likewise vollyball_teams

7.User team type role: a user will be assigned with team and team type role

- a) Sam (user) be manager of two or more teams(basketball-team-1 , football-team-2).
- b) Another user can be owner and coach of basketball-team-1 and  manager of football-team-2
- c) Two users can have same role in a team like players in football-team-1
- d) depending on hierarchy of team types manager of higher team type can manage events of lower team types .

Like manager of football-team-2  can manage events of football-team-2 and all team types of volleyball and basketball but manager of vollyball-team-1 can manage events of his team only as this type is lowest in team type hierarchy

Actions for role hierarchy

- a) owner of a team can add/edit managers and  approve coaches added/updated by managers of same team.
- b) managers can add/edit coaches and approve palyers added/updated by coaches
- c) coaches can add/edit players

I want to implement this complicated mapping in eloquent relationships and same how to implement it in database (Oracle).

Comment: What is the exact problem that you have? "How to implement ...?" Is a question that will only bring you trouble or no help on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lewis i want to implement.